# How to display real-time data which is stored in an IBM Cloud web app

Tags: embed

I have created a web app on IBM cloud which is displaying real-time data from an electrical sensor (this sensor is transmitting data on that web app using wi-fi). Now I want to display this data in a more organized form on to my company (Wordpress) site.

How can I do that?

Comment: hmm without knowing more information about the IBM cloud I don't know how one could answer this, have you checked the IBM cloud API docs?

Comment: +1 What Tom said, you need a summary/manifest of what IBM cloud endpoints/integrations are available for consumption, once you know what you can get from it, then a more pointed answer can be formed for the "how do I get it into or from WordPress" question.